# Meaning of "I'm kind of on a clock here"

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context

In the TV show *Friends*, there is the following conversation:

> — Did you ask him?
>   — No, I haven't had a chance yet.
>   — I'm kind of on a clock here.
>   — Oh, Fonzie.
>   — You know who I always liked? Mork.

So what does *on a clock* mean? Does it mean "in a hurry"?

Comment: *To be on the clock* means to be working. When you start your work for the day you *clock in* and at the end of the day you *clock out*. Thus one can calculate the time you've worked that day.

Comment: Thank you. The situation is that Phoebe is giving birth. So she is in labor. So do you think she's playing around with the phrase "in labor" ? Because I just realize from what you told me that, "on the clock" means working, and hence in labor ?

Comment: If used with the indefinite article ('a'), the phrase simply means the person speaking is under time pressure of some sort. It doesn't necessarily mean that person is working, and no puns on labor would be implied. If used with the definite article ('the'), it normally means the person is, as Armen says, working.

Comment: Wow i didn't detect such nuance here. Thanks !

Comment: I'd add to Armen: To be "on the clock" means that you are working, i.e. that someone else is paying you to work for him, and thus it would be dishonest to engage in personal business. "Sorry, can't chat with you right now, I'm on the clock."

Comment: You're saying the person who says "I'm on a clock here" was in labor? (Sorry, I never watched this program.) I think the implication, then, would be that, like someone who is supposed to be working cannot take time off to chat, she's busy delivering the baby and so can't take time off. Maybe the writer was thinking of a pun on "labor", but I'd guess was simply thinking of "busy with a more important responsibility".

Comment: I suspect she said "on the clock", and osager misremembered it a bit. I've never heard anybody say "on a clock". It would probably elicit laughter if it happened.

Comment: It was "on a clock", definitely. From here: http://www.friendscafe.org/scripts/s5/503.php

Comment: Osager, if the situation is that Phoebe is giving birth, she isn’t playing with the phrase "in labor" in the way you’re looking at.

The reference from childbirth to “On the clock" is simply to a process having started which will run its own course and take its own time, however much the person - here, mother - tries to control it.

The co-incidence of “being in labour” and “labouring” holds up only in speculation among non-native speakers.

Here, on “a” or “the” clock matters not.

Comment: The wonderfully formal "I do believe we have a timetable here" (the equerry admonishing Mycroft!) appears in 'A Scandal in Belgravia' and is otherwise a close paraphrase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I remember this scene vaguely. Phoebe was basically saying she *didn't have much time left* since she had already gone into labor. What she wanted was for Rachel (or was it Joey?) to ask Frank if she could keep one of the triplets she was having for him (yes I'm a major Friends geek). The question obviously had to be asked as soon as possible.

So basically being "on a clock" in this context means not having much time left for an action to be taken, or being in a hurry, as you said.

Comment: "We're on a clock. 30 minutes." from Terminator 5, Genisys. This is what Kyle says as Pops(Arny/Terminator), Sarah and Kyle enter an underground bunker for arming and kicking Skynet's butt.

Answer (score 1):

There are two slightly different meanings; "on the clock" normally means that you are working or that the time is costing you something. By analogy to being clocked-in at work or to a taxi/cab meter running.

But "against the clock" or "up against the clock" is used when you are working against a deadline - as in this case.

From a strictly accurate point I would say the line in the show should have been "I'm up against the clock here"

Comment: wow so many answers i can't judge anymore. and I can't find the original script neither. But i'm pretty sure it's just on a clock

Comment: @osager - probably, but American sitcoms aren't necessarily the gold standard for correct writing! Also phrases and idioms vary with time, region and dialect

Comment: In New York English, especially informally spoken (specifically a Brooklyn accent), a "the" following a word ending in "n" will often be pronounced as if it were n-schwa, giving the resultant sound of, "Hey, I'm onnuh clock here," with an emphasis on "clock" and a rising tone from "on" to "clock".